# Need idea with ajax concept project

Tags: php, ajax, project, chat

i've create a chat in ajax, but i still have some problem that i can't recognize.
When the page is loaded, the php load all the opened chat and relative mex, then there's an addmex ajax function: when the user hits enter it's called passing this.value and the cod_chat. The ajax function send these data to the php, which insert them into the db and add the last mex into the chat. Every X seconds an update function is called, to update the chat.
It all works until it gets to the addmex function: the php works, because it add the mex into the db, but for some reason it refresh the page. Could i use RTMP?

This is the code of the form:

```
<input type='text' class='chat_input' value='write something' onkeydown='if (event.keyCode == 13){addmex(this.value); this.value='';}'/>
```

and this is the code of the ajax function (don't worry about the php variables because this function is loaded by echo):

```
function addmex(mex)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","addmex.php?cod_contatto="+' . $cod_contatto . '+"&mex="+mex,false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("messaggi_' . $cod_contatto . '").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

I set Async as false because it respond slowly, and if i set true works only with some alert that let the server part complete. Any idea?

Comment: If your app is not commercial, go for *RTMFP*

Comment: I would use it to create a chat for a web app, that would earn by add, so it may be commercial use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your insert field implemented?  If it is in a HTML form, it will send the form when you hit enter. So if this is given, you need to prevent the default enter action in order to prevent the page refresh:
Just get the js event (onkeydown), do what you need to do and **return false**.

**EDIT**

You may assign the handler in a diffrent way:
Give the input an ID so this will work:

```
document.getElementById(yourID).onkeydown = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13){addmex(this.value); this.value='';}
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Your first code has a syntax error, it should be:

```
.... this.value="";}'/></form>
```

You cant use the same quotes in the inner String: '''' are like 2 strings, while '""' is one string in another.

**SOLUTION** *For those who happen to read this.*

The form tag was unnecessary and caused the page to refresh (sometimes preventing default does not work?!).

Finally there was the refreshing via ajax missing. Just do a setInterval() with the function and it should work all fine.

Comment: Thanks, i've totally forgot about the need of the return, i'm gonna test it now!

Comment: where should i put the retun, for you?

Comment: Put the return last in the event function. If a handler in JS return false, the default action is prevented.
So in your case: Put it last in the onkeydown property. But im not sure if it works with HTML attribute assigns.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work... it keep refreshing. Any idea about why it's so slow? It's only fault of the server?

Comment: If the client keeps refreshing its not the ervers fault. I guess the default action is still not prevented. Preventing default event actions is anoying (at least for me). So do you really need the <form>? If not, get rid of it. 
BTW: Not using the async-mode of ajax is slowing down. And maby try xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); instead of xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Comment: Thanks, trying it. Which alternatives do i have to the form? As you can see, i use both: one for the old browsers, one for the new ones.

Comment: You dont need the form if you dont want to actually send the form and its contents. So you can just do the input on its own - without the form. Should not change anything (maybe graphics).

Comment: Thanks, this solve the refreshing problem. Now, have you any idea about how to update the chat with new mex when the other user send one? Should i simply insert a refresh function that check every X seconds the db or there's an other way?

Comment: Yeah just do an ajax refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'd like to vote your answer, could you write the solution in the comment into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**I've made a mini project script with mysql and this works realy perfect ! You dont need HTTPS for to hidding ajax file. Try this. THIS 100 % WORKS !**

---

**MYSQL CODE :**

---

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ajax_sessions`;
CREATE TABLE `ajax_sessions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` text NOT NULL,
  `sip` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `open` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

**CREATE FILE NAMED security.php AND INCLUDE IT INTO MAIN PAGE LIKE index.php
INSERT AND SAVE THIS CODE**

---

```
    // INCLUDE YOUR MYSQL CONNECT FILE
    require '/engine/config/mysql.php';

    // SESSION IP ADDRESS
    $sip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // COUNT IF TABLE FOR THIS IP ADDRESS EXISTS
    $count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ajax_sessions WHERE sip = '".$sip."'"));
    // COUNT VAR
    $count = $count['COUNT(*)'];
    // GENERATE RANDOM SESSION ID
    $sid = substr(str_shuffle("_-0123456789-_-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_"), 0, 50);

    // YOUR AJAX / XMLHTTP / (LOAD) CALL
    echo '
    <script>
    $("button").click(function() {
    $(".container").load("/ajax/request.php?sid='.$sid.'");
    });

    // CHEC IF CODE WORKS
    console.log("Ajax - Session control is activated.");

    </script>';

    // IF TABLE FOR THIS IP ADDRESS NOT EXISTS INSERT IP,SESSION AND OPEN SESSION.
    if($count<1) {mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajax_sessions (sid,sip,open) VALUES ('".$sid."','".$sip."','1')");
} else {
    // IF THIS IP ALREADY EXISTS INTO TABLE JUST UPDATE IT AND INSERT SESSION ID.
    mysql_query("UPDATE ajax_sessions SET sid = '".$sid."', sip = '".$sip."', open = '1'");
}
```

---

**PLACE THIS PHP CODE IN TO AJAX FILE**

---

```
// IF GET sid ( SESSION ID )
if($_GET) {

// CHECK IF SESSION ID IS SET
if(isset($_GET['sid']) && $_GET['sid'] == $_GET['sid'] && !empty($_GET['sid'])) { 

// SESSION REMOTE IP ADDRESS
$sip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

// GET SESSION ID WE GOT
$sid = $_GET['sid']; 

// COUNT IF THIS SESSION EXISTS IN MYSQL BASE
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ajax_sessions WHERE sid = '".$sid."' AND sip = '".$sip."' AND open = '1'"));

// COUNT SESSION
if($fetch['COUNT(*)'] == 1) {

// IF SESSION EXISTS CATCH IP ADDRESS AND CLEAR SESSION ID FOR THIS IP AND CLOSE IT, BUT NOT REMOVE
mysql_query("UPDATE ajax_sessions SET sid = NULL, sip = '".$sip."', open = '0'");

} else {

// DIE IF SESSION NOT EXISTS AND DO NOT SHOW CODE
die;

}

// IF IT WORKS OPEN JS CONSOLE LOG WITH F12 FOR GOOGLE CHROME 
echo '<script>console.log("Session unseted !")</script>';

}

// AJAX POST CONTENT. IF POST
} else if($_POST) {

echo 'Call request';

}
```

---

I KNOW THAT THIS IS HARD TO UNDERSTAND BUT ITS REALY WORKS AND I'M USE IT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try **ArcusNode** or **Cumulus**. I suggest [**ArcusNode**](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/ArcusNode) to proceed with. It's an OpenRTMFP protocol.